USB to ethernet adapter not in lsusb (via thoundbolt port)
So I am having a strange problem. Short story is, I have a Lenovo monitor P32P-30 which has a USB to Ethernet adapter, so I connect my laptop (Yoga 71i 12700h) to this monitor via thunderbolt port, my laptop does NOT list the wired network in lsusb, as if it does not exist.
Long story:

I had it working with Deepin 20.9 with kernel 6.1.x (don't remember exact number).  It just worked, nothing special.

What happened was, I installed the new deepin release, it comes with 2 kernels, 6.6.x and 6.9.x, I tried both, same result, see below.

All other ports on the monitor works.  It has USB ports, I conntected a USB externet HDD on the monitor, Canon printer etc, they all showed up in lsusb except the realtek ethernet port.

Removed all devices connected to the USB on the monitor, still doesn't work.  Tried to replug in, unplug and replug 1 million times, same result.

Tried dmesg -w then plug it in, no error message 5 using xhci_hcd

To rule out the adapter itself, plugged the monitor to a Macbook pro, the realtek ethernet adapter showed up and connected to internet instantly.

Installed deepin v23 with kernel 6.9.x on a Beelink SER7 mini box, and the adapter showed up immedidately and connected instantly.

Reinstalled Deepin 23 on this Yoga 7i 12700H again, still doesn't show up, as if it did not exist.


So what could be the issue?
Thanks
Update: seems the problem is Deepin's support of thunderbolt 4.  Added kernel param pcie_ports=compat, now ip a displays the adapter, but state is DOWN.  Seems thundbolt is not working:
Here is lspci -v:
2e:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Thunderbolt 4 Bridge [Goshen Ridge 2020] (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Thunderbolt 4 Bridge [Goshen Ridge 2020]
        !!! Unknown header type 7f
        I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00008fff [size=16K] [32-bit]
        Memory behind bridge: 52000000-5e1fffff [size=194M] [32-bit]
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000006130000000-000000614bffffff [size=448M] [64-bit]

2f:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Thunderbolt 4 Bridge [Goshen Ridge 2020] (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Thunderbolt 4 Bridge [Goshen Ridge 2020]
        !!! Unknown header type 7f

2f:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Thunderbolt 4 Bridge [Goshen Ridge 2020] (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Thunderbolt 4 Bridge [Goshen Ridge 2020]
        !!! Unknown header type 7f
        I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff [size=4K] [32-bit]
        Memory behind bridge: 52000000-55efffff [size=63M] [32-bit]
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000006130000000-00000061394fffff [size=149M] [64-bit]

2f:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Thunderbolt 4 Bridge [Goshen Ridge 2020] (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Thunderbolt 4 Bridge [Goshen Ridge 2020]
        !!! Unknown header type 7f
        I/O behind bridge: 00006000-00006fff [size=4K] [32-bit]
        Memory behind bridge: 55f00000-59dfffff [size=63M] [32-bit]
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000006139500000-00000061429fffff [size=149M] [64-bit]

2f:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Thunderbolt 4 Bridge [Goshen Ridge 2020] (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Thunderbolt 4 Bridge [Goshen Ridge 2020]
        !!! Unknown header type 7f
        I/O behind bridge: 00007000-00007fff [size=4K] [32-bit]
        Memory behind bridge: 59e00000-5dcfffff [size=63M] [32-bit]
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000006142a00000-000000614befffff [size=149M] [64-bit]

2f:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Thunderbolt 4 Bridge [Goshen Ridge 2020] (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Thunderbolt 4 Bridge [Goshen Ridge 2020]
        !!! Unknown header type 7f
        Memory behind bridge: 5dd00000-5dffffff [size=3M] [32-bit]

56:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller (2) I225-LMvP (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Ethernet Controller (2) I225-LMvP
        !!! Unknown header type 7f
        Memory at 5dd00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Memory at 5df00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Expansion ROM at 5de00000 [disabled] [size=1M]
        Kernel driver in use: igc
        Kernel modules: igc


So how fix that?

OK, figured it out.  The thundlerbolt security level is set to user, and it is not authorized.  After installing the package bolt, and run systemctl start bolt.service or reboot, ethernet port appeared immedidately.
Thanks to @Marcelo for the hits, which led me to dig into the thunderbolt service.

Sure.   Happy the answer and comments helped.  Did you have to keep the pcie_ports configuration in the kernel command line?

Please, notice that setting the thunderbolt security level to authorized indiscriminately makes you vulnerable to DMA attacks from the device.  A good way to workaround this is to create a udev rule that only easy the security for your specific device.

@Marcelo No, I don't need the pcie_ports in the kernel params.

@Marcelo, I will look into the udev rule.  Thanks for the suggestion!

This is a generic udev rule that you can add to your /etc/udev/rules.d/99-thunderbot.rules (you can create the file if it doesn't exist):
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="thunderbolt", ATTR{authorized}=="0", ATTR{authorized}="1"
Note: you'll have to add other ATTR comparisons in addition to ATTR{authorized}=="0" in order to specifically identify your device, otherwise this will set the authorized flag to "1" for every device

Thanks!  I will give it a try shortly!

I'm not sure if this is the case for your laptop, but for my MacBookPro I had to play with the "pcie_ports" parameter in the Kernel Command Line for the correct events and actual bus detection of the Thunderbolt port and connected devices.
The possible values include:
pcie_ports=compat
pcie_ports=native
pcie_ports=auto
Hope this helps

Thanks, so before I try that just want to let you know the other devices connected on the monitor are working fine, only the ethernet is not working.  So should I give it a try? :)

The Thunderbolts port in notebooks have multiple facets.  They can behave as usb ports, display ports and actual thunberbot ports.  showing up or not depends on the actual device type.  I also had devices that are pure-usb devices that showed up while thunderbot devices don't before tweaking.  This doesn't assure it will work, but worth trying as it helped in my case.

Actually, it shows up, not in lsusb but in ip a command.  Status shows 2: enp86s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000     link/ether b8:4a:64:8f:16:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 

Just to add, with pcie_ports=compat now ip a displays the adapter, but was detected as 56:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller (2) I225-LMvP (rev 03), but it should be a realtek.

Thunderbolt devices can actually be pcie external devices, not USB devices.  This might be your case.  If you are really sure it used to show up as a USB device, chances are your device was not supported and used to be detected in some kind of fallback usb mode.  At some point, it started to be supported and now shows up as a pcie device.  If this is the case, you have a more efficient driver working now.  Why does it make that much difference for you that it should be listed as a USB one?

Because it is not working (ethernet port doesn't show up).  ip a doesn't show the adapter without pcie_ports=compat.  With this param, it shows up, but state is DOWN.  Also lspci -v has many thunderbolt errors (see main post with updated information)  Thanks

Try removing the adapter and check if the new pci device still shows up in lspci after rebooting.  This may actually not be your adapter, but an internal ethernet port in the chipset (that not necessarily has a connector).

OK, more test results.  1. unplug and reboot, it does not show up in ip a command. So confirmed it is indeed the adapter from the monitor (also tested with ubuntu live cd). 2. Plug it in after the PC is booted, it won't show up in ip a.  3. It only show up in ip a command if it is plugged then boot the computer.  For #3, the state shows DOWN, unable to bring it up.
